# как могу оптимизировать этот код помогите пожалуйста

Tags: php

```
   function newEasyKeyboard($array = [], $resize_keyboard = true, $one_time_keyboard = false) {
            for ($i = 0;$i < count($array);$i++) {
                if ($keyboard == []) $keyboard = [];
                if ($i % 2 == 0) {
                    $mas_out = [];
            $newone = array_keys($array[$i]);

                    for ($j = 0;$j < count($newone);$j++) {
                        $m = [];

                        for ($k = 0;$k < count($array[$i][$newone[$j]]);$k++) {
                            if (mb_strpos('contact',$newone[$j])!==false) $m = ['text' => $array[$i][$newone[$j]],'request_contact'=>true];
                            elseif(mb_strpos('location',$newone[$j])!==false) $m = ['text' => $array[$i][$newone[$j]],'request_location'=>true];
                else $m = ['text' => $array[$i][$newone[$j]]];


                        }
                        $mas_out[] = $m;
                    }
                    $mkeyboard = array_chunk($mas_out, $array[$i + 1]);
                    $keyboard = array_merge($keyboard, $mkeyboard);
                } else continue;
            }
            return json_encode(compact('resize_keyboard', 'keyboard', 'one_time_keyboard'));
        }
```

Comment: $keyboard = $bot->newEasyKeyboard([
  ['location'=>'location yuboring','test2','test3','test4'],3,
  ['contact'=>'contact yuboring','test2','test3'],2,
 ]);

Comment: $keyboard не объявлен. Зачем там проверка?
Опиши лучше что требуется сделать.

Comment: если я убру то array_merge не будет работать корректно

Comment: Ну ты получается мержишь (объединяешь) пустой массив с полученным. Но зачем? Это вообще бесполезное действие.
К слову твой код вообще не работает)

Comment: К стати оно уже работает :)